# Sublime Text: How to recognize (and highlight) C# .NET Classes, Methods, and Property names?

Tags: c#, .net, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I would really like to use Sublime Text more for light C# coding; however, I would prefer for Sublime Text to identify .NET Classes, Methods, and Property names; and, use colors from my custom color scheme to to highlight them.

I installed "C# Compile and Run" as well as "completion"; however, they didn't make any difference.  I'm hoping someone can point me to an addon that could add this enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't program in C#, so I can't speak from personal experience, but a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=c%23+tmlanguage) turned up the [`csharp-tmbundle`](https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle), a language definition for TextMate that should also work for Sublime Text. Go to your `Packages` folder on the command line (`%APPDATA%\Sublime Text X\Packages` where `X` is either `2` or `3`) and run

```
git clone https://github.com/wintermi/csharp-tmbundle.git C#
```

and you should now have a `C#` option in the `View -> Syntax` menu, as well as the syntax menu accessible via the far right option in the status bar. For determining which scopes are currently active under your cursor, I highly recommend the [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways) plugin available via Package Control.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this answer is close enough.  I wasn't able to get the package to work when I installed it using the git command line (it installed, but just didnt work).  I had to actually use Sublime Text 3's Package Control to download and install it.

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work with ST3. I discovered that I could not use "C#" as the folder name. As soon as I changed the plugin folder name from %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\C# to %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\CSharp it started working wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the syntax definitions of the C# language. These are hidden inside `.sublime-package` files which are basicly zip files. You can use the plugin [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) of which one of the features is that it can extract the files and packages to the `Packages` directory.

Once you've installed the plugin, open the command palette and type `prv` to get the `Package Resource Viewer` options. Choose `Open Resource` and navigate to the `C#`. You then need to search for the `.tmLanguage` file. This will allow you to make changes to the parsing.

See:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html

Comment: I installed "Csharp-tmbundle" and opened the respective C#.tmLanguage file using Package Resource Viewer.  However, I can't figure out where to define color scheme colors names for each respective scope name.  I am hoping all pertinent scopes are already defined in the C#.tmLanguage file... and, only have to specify the right colors.